# Laravel 5.1 collective template issue

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I having issues with laravel 5.1 template. Following are the screenshot from the browser and code editor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following are the code I add to config\app.php

```
Providers:
 Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class

aliases:
 'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
 'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class
```

And yet I cant render proper form. Thanks

Comment: Did you do compose dump-autoload?

Comment: And it must be `{!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail Address') !!}`

Comment: @aldrin27 yes you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
{!! Form::label('email', 'E-mail Address') !!}
```